# Perform action on Google Cloud Function install/setup

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, grpc-python

I'm writing a cloud function that process a pub/sub message which contains a grpc message. I would like, at install/(re)deploy time, the cloud function to perform some action: pull the protobuf definition from some GitHub repository and generate the correspondent python code with grpcio-tools, roughly in the same line of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52994857/how-do-i-generate-python-grpc-code-from-within-a-setuptools-installer-setup-py).

So far I can only find in the documentation how to add dependencies, however I'm looking for some sort of on install "hook": something that would allow me to perform some actions *before* the function is actually deployed.

Is this possible? Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions has no such hook.  You can perform the work in a script on the machine that performs the deployment.  It's not uncommon to write scripts to automate work like this.