# grpcio-tools protoc.main gives 'missing output directives' error

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python

I'd like to use `protoc.main(...)` in order to generate python gRPC files during runtime as below.

```py
from grpc_tools import protoc
args = "--proto_path=. --python_out=grpc --grpc_python_out=grpc alpha.proto"
result = protoc.main(c)
```

The above code gives **'missing output directives'** error with result code `1`.

However, below workaround to put `alpha.proto` as a commandline args works. It means `alpha.proto` file is fine.

```py
import subprocess
result = subprocess.call("python -m grpc_tools.protoc " + args, shell=True)
```

The possible causes are (1) `protoc.main` does *encode* to each character as below code, or (2) `protoc.main` wrongly resolves argument paths internally.

```py
def main(command_arguments):
    """Run the protocol buffer compiler with the given command-line arguments.

  Args:
    command_arguments: a list of strings representing command line arguments to
        `protoc`.
  """
    command_arguments = [argument.encode() for argument in command_arguments]
    return _protoc_compiler.run_main(command_arguments)
```

How can I use `protoc.main` correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will generate python files in `proto` directory where `.proto` files reside.

```py
proto_files = ["proto/file1.proto", "proto/file2.proto"]

from grpc_tools import protoc
for file in proto_files:
    grpc_tools.protoc.main([
        'grpc_tools.protoc',
        '--proto_path=.',
        '--python_out=.',
        '--grpc_python_out=.',
        file
    ])
```

I've got a hint from the answer; https://stackoverflow.com/a/54236739/361100

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the medium tutorial for golang protobufs, **DO NOT COPY AND PASTE** the:

`protoc --go_out=. *.proto`

command, because the `--` are not real `-`'s (dash, etc.), so hand typing the command fixed my problem.

I received this error due to copy and pasting improper characters

I hope you learn from my silly mistake :)